# Why are question previews sometimes in alt-text?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface, tooltips

When browsing Stack Overflow (and Meta), I've noticed a difference between some pages:

- Lists of questions under the "question" URL (i.e. when you click the "**Questions**" button) and associated tabs display the preview content below the title.
- Lists of questions **outside** of this URL (i.e. when you click the Stack Overflow logo) display the preview content in alt-text (when you mouseover the title).

Why is this?

I ask because I wonder why I can't scan over the contents of my "Interesting" list without having to either hover over questions (a second or so before the popup appears), or navigate to the content itself. Maybe there's an option I haven't found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "abbreviated" form (question intro only in the `title` text) is used on the homepage, where you want to show a high number of questions, in the hope that some of them interest you.

On the other pages you are filtering by something: tags, a search query, the "Unanswered" list, ... Here you are probably looking at every question in more detail. Showing the question text directly under the title instead of "hidden" in the `title` tag makes this possible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I found the feature I was looking for (mostly) at http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags.